# Snapshot restore failure

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create and restore snapshots to make a huge data set for my testing purposes. Initially, I created few snapshots and restored them successfully. But suddenly I can't restore newly created indices. I haven't made any changes to the system and the only difference is data volume is bigger now.

Elasticsearch version: 6.3.0, single node setup

**Snapshot Created**

```
 PUT /_snapshot/nuwan-backup2/snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3?wait_for_completion=true
    {
      "indices": "transactions-2018.11.27-reindexed-1543757375.64",
      "ignore_unavailable": true,
      "include_global_state": false
    }
```

**Output**

```
{
  "snapshot": {
    "snapshot": "snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3",
    "uuid": "JhsmFXmVR12OR-65fCtFXw",
    "version_id": 6030099,
    "version": "6.3.0",
    "indices": [
      "transactions-2018.11.27-reindexed-1543757375.64"
    ],
    "include_global_state": false,
    "state": "SUCCESS",
    "start_time": "2018-12-12T12:32:26.645Z",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946645,
    "end_time": "2018-12-12T12:32:26.750Z",
    "end_time_in_millis": 1544617946750,
    "duration_in_millis": 105,
    "failures": [],
    "shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "failed": 0,
      "successful": 5
    }
  }
}
```

**Snapshot status**

```
GET /_snapshot/nuwan-backup2/snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3/_status
```

**Output**

```
{
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "snapshot": "snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3",
      "repository": "nuwan-backup2",
      "uuid": "JhsmFXmVR12OR-65fCtFXw",
      "state": "SUCCESS",
      "include_global_state": false,
      "shards_stats": {
        "initializing": 0,
        "started": 0,
        "finalizing": 0,
        "done": 5,
        "failed": 0,
        "total": 5
      },
      "stats": {
        "number_of_files": 0,
        "processed_files": 0,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946662,
        "time_in_millis": 78
      },
      "indices": {
        "transactions-2018.11.27-reindexed-1543757375.64": {
          "shards_stats": {
            "initializing": 0,
            "started": 0,
            "finalizing": 0,
            "done": 5,
            "failed": 0,
            "total": 5
          },
          "stats": {
            "number_of_files": 0,
            "processed_files": 0,
            "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
            "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946662,
            "time_in_millis": 78
          },
          "shards": {
            "0": {
              "stage": "DONE",
              "stats": {
                "number_of_files": 0,
                "processed_files": 0,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946696,
                "time_in_millis": 17
              }
            },
            "1": {
              "stage": "DONE",
              "stats": {
                "number_of_files": 0,
                "processed_files": 0,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946722,
                "time_in_millis": 18
              }
            },
            "2": {
              "stage": "DONE",
              "stats": {
                "number_of_files": 0,
                "processed_files": 0,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946662,
                "time_in_millis": 18
              }
            },
            "3": {
              "stage": "DONE",
              "stats": {
                "number_of_files": 0,
                "processed_files": 0,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946662,
                "time_in_millis": 18
              }
            },
            "4": {
              "stage": "DONE",
              "stats": {
                "number_of_files": 0,
                "processed_files": 0,
                "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "processed_size_in_bytes": 0,
                "start_time_in_millis": 1544617946696,
                "time_in_millis": 20
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Snapshot Restore**

```
POST /_snapshot/nuwan-backup2/snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3/_restore
    {
      "indices": "snapshot-x2",
      "ignore_unavailable": true,
      "include_global_state": true,
      "rename_pattern": "s(.+)",
      "rename_replacement": "s$1"
    }
```

**Output**

```
{
  "snapshot": {
    "snapshot": "snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3",
    "indices": [],
    "shards": {
      "total": 0,
      "failed": 0,
      "successful": 0
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**
No new index generated!

Comment: Where is the `snapshot-x2` index in your snapshot? the index you backed up is `transactions-2018.11.27-reindexed-1543757375.64`.

Comment: Thanks @AHT for pointing out, it was my mistake, I thought it should be the new index name.

Comment: Glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I have incorrectly configured restore request, it should be

```
POST /_snapshot/nuwan-backup2/snapshot_transactions-cl2-2018.11.27-reindexed-x3/_restore
    {
      "indices": "transactions-2018.11.27-reindexed-1543757375.64",
      "ignore_unavailable": true,
      "include_global_state": true,
      "rename_pattern": "transactions-2018.11.27-reindexed-1543757375.64",
      "rename_replacement": "snapshot-x2"
    }
```